# magento 2.3.4 Errors after moving site to live domain within the same server [SOLVED]

Tags: magento2.3, magento2.3.4

I have created a magento 2.3.4 site on a test server var/www/domain.es/developer/ 
Once the site is tested and working I have changed the location by plesk (copy site) to var/www/domain.es but what is my surprise when I check the following

1) When I do an export I save it in var/www/domain.es/developer/var/export

2) The files .update_status.txt .update_cronjob_status .setup_cronjob_status are still updated in var/www/domain.es/developer/ and do not exist in var/www/domain.es

3) In the DB cron_schedule.sales_clean_orders continues searching in var/www/domain.es/developer/ and gives error Notice: Undefined index: simple_sku in /var/www/vhosts/domain.es/developer/vendor/magento/module-inventory-configurable-product/Plugin/Sales/GetSkuFromOrderItem.php on line 36

And more things that are possibly all related.

Any help in solving this?

Comment: It can be related to https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/21663, not sure about but it sound the same

Comment: It may have loose the simple_sku options from your configurable product,  did you have made any changes to make it works?

Answer (score 0):

It was resolved as follows:

1. I reinstalled a copy in the old location `var/www/domain.es/developer`
2. From commands I deleted the old cronjob. `bin/magento cron:remove`
3. I go back to the new location `var/www/domain.es` and from command I create the new cronjob. `bin/magento cron:install`
4. I delete everything in the old location. `var/www/domain.es/developer`